# Is it possible to use Framer Motion in React with pug

Tags: reactjs, next.js, pug, jsx, framer-motion

I am using multiple technologies for my advanced React web page development
I previously used AOS for animating my react components simply, also tried GreenSock once but it didn't fit my needs...
I am using Next js and pug js in Next js through https://github.com/pugjs/babel-plugin-transform-react-pug

And want to use Framer motion for the same but
`motion.div` changes to `<motion className="div">`
Could anyone please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Next.js Application, go to  `.babelrc` fil at the root(if not create one and add

```
{
  "plugins": [
    ["transform-jsx-classname-components", {
      "objects": ["motion"]
    }]
  ]
}
```

That's good, your `final .babelrc` should look as

```
{
  "presets": ["next/babel"],
  "plugins": [
    "transform-react-pug",
    [
      "transform-jsx-classname-components",
      {
        "objects": ["motion"]
      }
    ],
    "transform-react-jsx"
  ]
}
```

This is good to go for React's framer motion using pug
And also please note : There is no syntax highlighting for the same as I tried over the time

..
In case of create-react-app please make sure to add the `.babelrc` contents in `package.json` after ejecting (npm eject), You will have a "babel" field in `package.json`, just add these plugins property inside that field..

Still this isn't the exact solution,

> Now you will have to use `motion.Div` wherever you want animations
> instead of `motion.div` (i.e, uppercase)

Anyways this means that you cannot animate elements directy but you can animate elements, you will always need to use motion.Div or motion.Span...

Hope this Helps

Edit: You could also add into import => as

Example `import {motion as Motion } from 'framer-motion';`

But you still have to use `Motion.Div` in pug