# How to setup the Pug for Next.js?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, pug

Almost no search results for "nextjs pug". Google suggests the results for "n**u**xtjs pug" which is the completely different framework.

One of two relevant search results is [this issue](https://github.com/pugjs/babel-plugin-transform-react-pug/pull/48). The suggested minimal setup requires too much plugins (I can't understand why I need each of them), too complicated cofigurations and does not work with current versions.

> **package.json**
>
> ```json
> {
>   "devdependencies": {
>     "@babel/core": "^7.0.0-beta.51",
>     "@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx": "^7.0.0-beta.51",
>     "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.0.0-beta.51",
>     "@babel/preset-env": "^7.0.0-beta.51",
>     "@babel/runtime": "^7.0.0-beta.51",
>     "babel-core": "7.0.0-bridge.0",
>     "babel-plugin-transform-react-pug": "git://github.com/shirohana/babel-plugin-transform-react-pug.git#dist"
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> **.babelrc.js**
>
> ```js
> module.exports = function (api) {
>  api.env()
>  return {
>     presets: [
>       ['@babel/env', { useBuiltIns: 'entry' }]
>     ],
>     plugins: [
>       ['babel-plugin-transform-react-pug'],
>       ['@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx'],
>       ['@babel/plugin-transform-runtime']
>     ]
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> https://github.com/pugjs/babel-plugin-transform-react-pug/pull/48#issuecomment-406466928

Other relevant search result is [Is it possible to use Framer Motion in React with pug](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65879863/4818123) question. I tried below solution:

```
{
  "presets": ["next/babel"],
  "plugins": [
    "transform-react-pug",
    [
      "transform-jsx-classname-components"
    ],
    "transform-react-jsx"
  ]
}
```

It's very interesting, but sometimes in works, sometimes - no.
I tried to create two projects. Firstly it works in both projects but then broke with error:

```
ReferenceError: React is not defined
at HomePage (C:\Users\****\Build\InteractiveImplementation\server\pages\index.js:63:3)
    at processChild (C:\Users\****\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.node.development.js:3353:14)
    at resolve (C:\Users\****\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.node.development.js:3270:5)
    at ReactDOMServerRenderer.render (C:\Users\****\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.node.development.js:3753:22)
    at ReactDOMServerRenderer.read (C:\Users\****\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.node.development.js:3690:29)
    at renderToString (C:\Users\****\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.node.development.js:4298:27)
    at Object.renderPage (C:\Users\****\node_modules\next\dist\next-server\server\render.js:53:854)
    at Function.getInitialProps (C:\Users\****\Build\InteractiveImplementation\server\pages\_document.js:556:19)
    at loadGetInitialProps (C:\Users\****\node_modules\next\dist\next-server\lib\utils.js:5:101)
    at renderToHTML (C:\Users\****\node_modules\next\dist\next-server\server\render.js:53:1145)
```

This error will leave even don't use the Pug:

```js
import React, { ReactNode } from "react";


class TestComponent extends React.Component<TestComponent.Properties,TestComponent.State> {

  public state: TestComponent.State = {
    count: 0
  }

  public render(): ReactNode {
    // return pug`
    //   main
    //     div ${this.props.message}
    //     div props.message
    // `;
    return (
      <div onClick={() => this.increment(1)}>
        {this.props.message} {this.state.count}
      </div>
    )
  }

  private increment(amt: number): void {
    this.setState((state: TestComponent.State): TestComponent.State => ({
      count: state.count + amt,
    }));
  };
}

namespace TestComponent {

  export type Properties = {
    message: string;
  }

  export type State = {
    count: number;
  };
}

export default TestComponent;
```

You may want to know what I did directly before application broken.
Well, I had not record each my of actions, but I had not make some big changes like directories renamig or configuration editing directly before first failed launch. Anyway, we need know where config is wrong and how to fix it.

Comment: Hi, just want to know why you would want to use Pug ? Isn't the point of using NextJs is to leverage the power of React? Anyhow, NextJs is built specifically for React, and Pug seems to have been renamed to Jade - I suppose "React + Jade" can yield better results. I found: [An old repo of someone doing Jade and NextJs](https://github.com/alvin/wirebase) and [Pug's babel plugin transform React](https://github.com/pugjs/babel-plugin-transform-react-pug). Again, React is NOT made with Pug in mind (but JSX instead), so you might need to lots of configs to work

Comment: @BaoHuynhLam, From the viewpoint of my methodologies, the writing of XML-like languages is a routine which must be completely excluded from modern development. The Pug gives best combination of functionality and syntax brevity. "Anyhow, NextJs is built specifically for React, and Pug seems to have been renamed to Jade" - really? AFAK Jade has been renamed to Pug. Pug returns to Jade? "Again, React is NOT made with Pug in mind" - I don't going to obey the limitations established by framework developers. Needs and only needs must to establish the limitations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to import this in your `pages/index.tsx`

```
import React from "react";
```

For Babel transpilation of any jsx code, react import is needed. Import react wherever you use jsx code snippets. This fixes your issue.

Comment: It works! I can't thank you enough... The 50 points of reputation is not much, but better than just words.